# Rails not found even though it appears on "gem list"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've looked at people with similar issues, but everyone just says "Thanks for the help" without going over exactly how they solved their issue. I'm completely new to programming.

basically my $ gem list output gives:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.6)
actionpack (3.2.6)
activemodel (3.2.6)
activerecord (3.2.6)
activeresource (3.2.6)
activesupport (3.2.6)
arel (3.0.2)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.1.4)
erubis (2.7.0)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.0)
journey (1.0.4)
json (1.7.3)
mail (2.4.4)
mime-types (1.19)
multi_json (1.3.6)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (3.2.6)
railties (3.2.6)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.12)
rubygems-bundler (1.0.3)
rvm (1.11.3.4)
sprockets (2.1.3)
thor (0.15.3)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.33)
```

but when i input $ rails -v i get:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ rails -v
The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install rails
```

Some other threads say it is a path issue, but I have no idea what i'm doing if i fiddle with .bash or path and feel like i need someone to hold my hand through this =/.

my echo $PATH output is:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin/bin:/usr/games:/home/user/.rvm/bin
```

$ gem environment output:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.24
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-04-20 patchlevel 194) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
     - /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "install" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri"
     - "update" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

I apologize if my question is not formatted correctly or not clear. I'm completely new to programming and this site.

Comment: Please try "bundle exec rails".

Comment: Check wherever `/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin` contains `rails`.

Answer (score 0):

if you on server, check .bash_profile and .bashrc.  When you sign in and check your environment variables, it may be different from variables via ssh.